# How can I get Elmah to send email using our email gateway web service?

Tags: asp.net, elmah

I realise this would require some sort of custom ErrorMailModule, but where do I start, if I can even do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the ELMAH source and look how they wrote their `ErrorMailModule`. It would be quite simple to change the code to use your web service. (Just make sure that you do not violate the ELMAH license.)